# Cached Network Image not displaying

Tags: flutter, dart, pub.dev

The image is not getting loaded using CachedNetworkImage, but when i use Image.network it works without any issues. I used the code from the official documentation.

```
 GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.pink,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              imageUrl: imgUrl,
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
              placeholder: (context, url) => const SizedBox(
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

The Error i got

```
ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationSupportDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
E/flutter ( 8192): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
platform_channel.dart:308
E/flutter ( 8192): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8192): #1      getApplicationSupportDirectory
path_provider.dart:78
E/flutter ( 8192): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8192): #2      CacheObjectProvider._getPath
cache_object_provider.dart:196
E/flutter ( 8192): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8192): #3      CacheObjectProvider.open
cache_object_provider.dart:28
E/flutter ( 8192): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8192): #4      CacheStore._getCacheDataFromDatabase
cache_store.dart:112
E/flutter ( 8192): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Here is the pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Here is the pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Please provide pubspec.yaml and that class code where this gridview builder resides.